# c# restart for loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, restart

So I have these few lines of code:

```
string[] newData = File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
int length = newData.Length;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    if (Condition)
    {
       //do something with the first line
    }
    else
    {
      //restart the for loop BUT skip first line and start reading from the second
    }
}
```

I've tried with goto, but as you can see, if I start the for loop again, it'll start from the first line.

So how can I restart the loop and change the starting line(getting different key from the array)?

Comment: If condition is true do you only want to read the first line, and if condition is false then only read from line 2 to the end?

Comment: Also note your `i <= newData.Length` should be `<`.

Comment: If it's true, I'm doing some job there with that first line and then with the second and etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd argue that a `for loop` is the wrong type of loop here, it doesn't correctly express the intent of the loop, and would definitely suggest to me that you're not going to mess with the counter.

```
int i = 0;
while(i < newData.Length) 
{
    if (//Condition)
    {
       //do something with the first line
       i++;
    }
    else
    {
        i = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: But this is just an ugly formatted for loop .... Agreed that the OP should shop for something else though.

Comment: No, it's a while loop. Yes you could do it with a for loop, but I'd consider it a code smell. For _implies_ doing something a number of times, or for a number of steps. That's not what this loop does.

Comment: +1, cuz I'm no deaf! :) for loop that goes back is an awful code.

Comment: @Henk: I don't think you're hearing me. It doesn't matter (and I don't care) that the two loops are equivalent, when some one reads the code they're likely to dismiss the `for` version as looping a number of times without catching the buried change to `i`. I'd argue it's the apparent simplicity of the `while` condition is what makes it a flag to the reader to check that this isn't as simple as it looks. IMHO the structure in the `for` version doesn't count for squat as you're subverting `for` and it's structure by breaking the most common use case of `for`.

Comment: This answer was the solution in my case. Thank you!

Comment: @Kirev: Glad to be of help pal :)

Answer (score 8):

Just change the `index` of the for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < newData.Length; i++) // < instead of <= as @Rawling commented.
{
    if (//Condition)
    {
       //do something with the first line
    }
    else
    {
      // Change the loop index to zero, so plus the increment in the next 
      // iteration, the index will be 1 => the second element.
      i = 0;
    }
}
```

Note that this looks like an excellent spaghetti code... Changing the index of a for loop **usually** indicate that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @Rawling. Didn't get you last comment. what did you mean?

Comment: +1 for spaghetti. Have argued a for loop isn't appropriate here, but it seems to be falling  on deaf ears :)

Comment: Yup, but if it fails on the second line, it'll continue reading the second one and going to the 3, 4, etc.
Basically I need to read every next line if condition fails.
Like:
first line is newData[0], second is newData[1]
I need to restart the loop and change the newData[i] every time.

PS: Sorry for my bad English

Comment: Rescinded means taken back/removed :)

Comment: And yeah. I think it's big mistake to use for loop here. I'll try to fix that.

Answer (score 4):

Just set `i = 0` in your `else` statement; the `i++` in the loop declaration should then set it to `1` and thus skip the first line.

Comment: He wants i to be 0. his best bet is to resize the array

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] newData = File.ReadAllLines(fileName)

for (int i = 0; i <= newData.Length; i++)
{
    if (//Condition)
    {
       //do something with the first line
    }
    else
    {
      //restart the for loop BUT skip first line and start reading from the second
      i = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would just reset `i` and resize the array

```
int length = newData.Length; // never computer on each iteration
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    if (condition)
    {
       //do something with the first line
    }
    else
    {
      // Resize array
      string[] newarr = new string[length - 1 - i];
      /*
       * public static void Copy(
       *    Array sourceArray,
       *    int sourceIndex,
       *    Array destinationArray,
       *    int destinationIndex,
       *    int length
       * )
       */
      System.Array.Copy(newData, i, newarr, 0, newarr.Length); // if this doesn't work, try `i+1` or `i-1`
      // Set array
      newData = newarr;
      // Restart loop
      i = 0;
    }
}
```